# Is this dark muscovado sugar safe to use?

Tags: food-safety, brown-sugar

I've got a batch of dark muscovado sugar that I rarely use, sitting in an airtight ziploc bag. Upon opening it today, I noticed that is gone very hard and some of the lumps are white inside. There's also a few darker ones.

Is this natural for this kind of sugar or has something happened to it (could be a fungus for all I know)?

[image: dark brown sugar with white and dark areas]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Muscovado sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscovado) is a [partially refined sugar](https://www.thekitchn.com/whats-the-difference-muscovado-145157).  Hence, it has a lot of what is essentially molasses contained in it.  The molasses can migrate, leaving whiter areas; also scraping with a spoon, e.g., can leave whiter areas.

To reconsitute, place in a jar with a [piece of bread](https://lespetitesgourmettes.com/tips/dont-throw-out-hard-brown-sugar/) or covered with a damp cloth (what I do).  Within a few hours, it should be nice and soft as sugar is quite [hygroscopic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygroscopy).  If you use bread, it (the bread) will probably be hard.

Comment: Thanks  I ground these lumps in a mortar (needed the sugar to make jerk). I'll do what you suggested with the rest.